# php include wont show my content in the php file

Tags: php, file, include

So, i have this form in a php file and i want it to show in this sliding div but it doesn't show any of the php file with my include file.  ANy suggestions?

I think im trying to inlcude the php file incorrectly

Here is the doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #wrap {

            }
            #box1 {
                background: red;
                width: 800px;
                height: 100px;
            }
            #box2 {
                background: blue;
                width: 800px;
                height: 200px;
                display: none;
            }
            #box3 {
                background: green;
                width: 800px;
                height: 100px;
            }
            .expand {

            }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $("#wrap a.expand").click(function() {
                    $('#box2').slideToggle('900');

                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="expand">Expanding/Collapse</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
            </p>

            <div id="box1" alt="box"></div>
            <div id="box2" alt="box">
                <?php include("test.php"); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="box3" alt="box"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the php file

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
    $ToEmail = 'email@email.site'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Portfolio Contact .com'; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?> 
Your message was sent
<?php 
} else { 
?> 
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="29%" class="bodytext">Your name:</td>
<td width="71%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext">Email address:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext">Comment:</td>
<td><textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" id="comment" class="bodytext"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext"> </td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form> 
<?php 
}; 
?>
```

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but is your test.php in the same directory?

Comment: Also I've never seen the `<>` operator used in php. Does that exist? Also do you have errors on and displaying? It could be a syntax error.

Comment: not the best case to use the include function.. you could just make it one page.

Comment: yes there is `<>` operator same as `!=`

Comment: ^Cool. I learned something new today.

Comment: Hmm, so how would i include the php form inside the div? what would u siggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]remove include file and use this jQuery Load, so your form will be load within div id box2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#wrap a.expand").click(function() {
                    $('#box2').slideToggle('900').load("test.php");

                });
            });

</script>
```

and change this if to `@$_POST["email"]<>''` with at sign and your error will be hide

Comment: Thanks! this did indeed load the php file. how did the @ remove the error?

Comment: this will skip your error on run time, but if you have huge errors in your code so you have to set error_reporting(). just put this in top of php file or if you are using database file so just put this in your database file because this file includes everywhere in website.

Comment: I highly recommend using `if (isset($_POST['email']) and $_POST["email"] != ''){` instead. Using @ represses errors and leads to a nightmare of a debugging experience. 

In this case it really is just much better to check whether it is set or not, rather than ignore PHP's advice.

Answer (score 1):

To easily eliminate the possibility that it cannot find the files test.php, replace your include() for [require()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). It does exactly the same, with the slight difference that not finding the file causes PHP to throw a fatal E_COMPILE error, thus making it blaringly obvious that something went wrong.

To aid your bug fixing, add the following two line to the very top of your PHP script (the main file):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will cause it to display all errors and notices right on the page, instantly showing you what went wrong in which file, on which line. Make sure you only use this in development though, you don't want your users to see detailed error messages about your back-end code.

Comment: thanks for the reply =] Now, when i replace included() with require(), it still did not show.  however after adding the debugging stuff to the php file it did show Notice: Undefined index: email in directoryplace on line 4

Comment: That makes sense. You'll want to check whether `$_POST['email']` is actually set before trying to check its value. You can use `isset($_POST['email'])` for this. [Manual entry on isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the page source and see if it is being included there. Your php file is included inside #box2, which has display set to none in the css, so it won't render even if it is being included.

Comment: hmm well the div is set to display: none until the slideToggle is activate.  I haven't used a php include before.  Is it supposed to show the php code in the source?

Comment: when i view the source when it's live it shows <?php include("test.php"); ?> between my div, like i "think" it should

Comment: Oh! I missed that point. Sorry. But, in the browser source, you should see the contents of what test.php has output and not the include statement. Your server might not be configured properly.